# Jenkins: How to complete a Gradle build with dependencies not in nexus?

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

I have a Gradle based project that is dependent on a couple of other projects one built via maven another via gradle. I can't push the other projects to our "enterprise" nexus repo because that involves much time/paperwork/pain. So is there a workaround I can use. Locally we simply build the other two projects so they are in our local repo and then can pull them from there. How can I achieve something similar on Jenkins? Each project is in a seprate Git repo.

Comment: Why can't you use the local repo workaround on Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do exactly the same thing inside Jenkins.

Before starting to build the gradle project, try checkout other projects firstly, and build them, so it will be installed into your local repo.

Then build the gradle as you did locally.

Br,

Tim